# XSL Dynamic Table Column Data with keys

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have started working with XSL and have an issue with unique dynamic column data. I have read about similar issues, but this situation seems different enough that I do not see the application of those solutions to this issue.

I have the following sample data set that can grow or shrink with a large number of `<ID>` and `<Date>` values:

```
<Report>
  <DataSets>
    <Data>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Date>201211</Date>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Date>201211</Date>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Date>201210</Date>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Date>201209</Date>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Date>201208</Date>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Date>201208</Date>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Date>201208</Date>
    </Data>
    <Data>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <Date>201208</Date>
    </Data>
  </DataSets>
</Report>
```

I am trying to obtain the XSL code to generate the following table:

```
ID  201208  201209  201210  201211
1     1       0       1       2 
2     1       1       0       0
3     2       0       0       0
```

The columns are dynamic and the column headers are the unique values of the `<Date>` elements. The rows are a collection of unique IDs with the data being the count of said `<ID>` for each `<Date>`. What I am struggling with is the dynamic creation of the count of the `<ID>` for each `<Date>`.

I have the following XSL file so far using keys which generates the table, but as you can see the Dates are hard coded atm.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0" >

<xsl:template match ="/" >
<html>
  <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Report/DataSets"/>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="Data_ID" match="Data" use="ID" />
<xsl:key name="Data_D" match="Data" use="Date"/>
<xsl:template match="Report/DataSets" >
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <xsl:for-each select="Data[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('Data_D', Date)[1])]"> 
      <xsl:sort select="Date"/>
      <!-- Dynamically add headers for each Date Column -->
      <th><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></th>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="Data[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('Data_ID', ID)[1])]"> 
  <xsl:sort select="ID"/>
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></td>
    <!-- Dynamically count IDs for each Date Column -->
    <!-- How to do this step? -->
    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('Data_ID', ID)[Date='201208'])"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('Data_ID', ID)[Date='201209'])"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('Data_ID', ID)[Date='201210'])"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('Data_ID', ID)[Date='201211'])"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is needed to replace these hard coded entries

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('Data_ID', ID)[Date='201208'])"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('Data_ID', ID)[Date='201209'])"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('Data_ID', ID)[Date='201210'])"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="count(key('Data_ID', ID)[Date='201211'])"/></td>
```

with dynamic code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same kind of `for-each` that you used for the headers

```
  <!-- store the full set of Data in a variable - we will need it inside the for-eaches -->
  <xsl:variable name="allData" select="Data"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$allData[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('Data_ID', ID)[1])]"> 
  <xsl:sort select="ID"/>
  <xsl:variable name="currentId" select="ID" />
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="$currentId"/></td>
    <!-- Dynamically count IDs for each Date Column -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$allData[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('Data_D', Date)[1])]"> 
      <xsl:sort select="Date"/>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('Data_ID', $currentId)[Date=current()/Date])"/>
      </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

The trick here is to save the `ID` from the outer `for-each` in a variable so you can access it while you are inside the inner `for-each`.

A possibly more efficient alternative would be to define a third key on both ID and Date

```
<xsl:key name="Data_ID_D" match="Data" use="concat(ID, '|', Date)" />
```

which would simplify the `count` expression

```
<xsl:for-each select="$allData[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('Data_D', Date)[1])]"> 
  <xsl:sort select="Date"/>
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('Data_ID_D', concat($currentId, '|', Date)))"/>
  </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to work, I get an empty table. The problem with the additional `for-each` is that the context is already set and it doesn't appear that you can move back up the path to create a new collection for the Date. Also, trying to combine the two keys doesn't seem to work because the keys need to be unique on there own, and combining results in non-unique row entries.

Comment: @JMO good point. You'll need to save the outer context in another variable so you can do the Muenchian trick in both for-each selects over the same base node set (see edit).